# Magento - UPS shipping returns error "Missing or invalid service code"

Tags: magento, ups

I'm configuring UPS shipping in a Magento installation and when I'm processing an order for shipment (adding products to pack!age, etc.) - after hitting "OK" to generate a shipping label, the error "Missing or invalid service code" is returned. I've tried changing the package type, weight, delivery confirmation options - all give the same result. The gateway URL in the UPS shipping method configuration is set to http://www.ups.com/using/services/rave/qcostcgi.cgi. See attached image for error message. Thanks in advance for any insight that could be provided!

[error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbocS.png)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of valid services codes (for Shipping Packages):

```
01 = Next Day Air
02 = 2nd Day Air
03 = Ground
07 = Express
08 = Expedited
11 = UPS Standard
12 = 3 Day Select
13 = Next Day Air Saver
14 = Next Day Air Early AM
54 = Express Plus
59 = 2nd Day Air A.M.
65 = UPS Saver
82 = UPS Today Standard
83 = UPS Today Dedicated Courier
84 = UPS Today Intercity
85 = UPS Today Express
86 = UPS Today Express Saver
```

Here is a list of valid services codes (for Shipping Freight):

```
308 = UPS Freight LTL 
309 = UPS Freight LTL – Guaranteed 
334 = UPS Freight LTL - Guaranteed A.M. 
349 = UPS Standard LTL
```

Comment: Where to add services codes in Magento for Shipping Packages?

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would throw in my answer for this, since I ran into this problem recently and this is the only question really referencing this that I could find, and the answer is less than definitive with a solution.

For UPS to generate shipping labels, you need to have it set up with the XML API in your configuration. When it is not set up with the XML API and an order is placed with ground shipping, the service code that gets set in the database for the order is "ups_GND". The XML API however is looking for a service code of "ups_03". Since this is set for the order in the table **sales_flat_order** under the field **shipping_method**, all of the requests to the XML API are going to use the wrong service code. The list of service codes that the previous answer gives are correct, you just have to replace the part after "ups_" with the correct number. Once you switch to the XML API, all orders will have the correct code.

Hopefully this will give a little more instruction for anyone looking to impliment a fix for this issue.